# Use case when and count into Select

Tags: mysql, sql

please advise. 
Need to add into Select one value combined from more columns.
I have column `dtmStartProcess`(here is date) and `intProcessAfterDays`(here is number).

Need to get value `EstimatedAfterProcess` which has condition, `CASE WHEN` count value in `intProcessAfterDays` to `dtmStartProcess ELSE` the value in `intProcessAfterDays is NULL` add 15 days.

Not sure how to put it togehter.

Thank you

Comment: It's not easy to comprehend your question.  Try adding code and examples.

Comment: Recommended reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Please edit you question and include the tables' DDL, DML with some sample data for the tables, the expected results with that sample data and the query you came up with so far.

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow community!  We're glad you're here, and hope you find some help for your question.  (I ask that you please excuse our rude behavior, downvoting your question.)

Answer (score 0):

Several possible expressions to achieve it.

Personally, I would do something like this

```
 SELECT t.dtmStartProcess + INTERVAL IFNULL(t.intProcessAfterDays,15) DAYS AS dtmAfter 
      , t.dtmStartProcess
      , t.intProcesAfterDays
      , ...
   FROM mytable t 
  WHERE ...
```

The `IFNULL` could be replaced with equivalent `CASE` expression

```
 CASE WHEN t.intProcesAfterDays IS NULL THEN 15 ELSE t.intProcessAfterDays END
```

---

Basically, we're taking the datetime value and adding an interval to it.

```
  dtmStart + INTERVAL 2 DAYS
```

In the place of the literal 2 we're using an expression.

We can also use the `DATE_ADD` or `ADDDATE` function to achieve an equivalent result.

```
  DATE_ADD(dtmStart,INTERVAL 2 DAYS)
```

or

```
  DATEADD(dtmStart,2)
```